# Displaying Please Wait Window on a SeperateThread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a method that exports the contents of my `DataGrid` to a `CSV` file. I'm trying to display a `Window` that has an animation on it to ask the user to wait.

However, when I show the `Window` the animation freezes so I assumed that this is because as the excel method is running on the same thread it freezes.

What I have tried so far is this;

```
var waitWindow = new PleaseWaitWindow();

var newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    waitWindow.Show();
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
});

newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
newWindowThread.Start();

ExcelExport();

waitWindow.Close();
```

but this leads to an error;

`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

How can I start a new thread so that the animation does not freeze whilst the excel method is exporting?

Comment: I think that the Export operation should be performed in Non-UI thread

Comment: Why not run the `ExcelExport` method in a separate thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the creation of the window into the new Thread, use `ShowDialog` to make sure it blocks and close it via its own `Dispatcher`.

```
PleaseWaitWindow waitWindow = null;

var newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        waitWindow = new PleaseWaitWindow();
        waitWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
);

newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.Start();

ExcelExport();

waitWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    waitWindow.Close();
}));
```

Just make sure `waitWindow` is created before trying to close it, some kind of IPC barrier would be good here. For Example (quick and dirty):

```
PleaseWaitWindow waitWindow = null;
AutoResetEvent loaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);

var newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        waitWindow = new PleaseWaitWindow();
        loaded.Set();
        waitWindow.ShowDialog();
    });

newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.Start();

ExcelExport();

loaded.WaitOne();

waitWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    waitWindow.Close();
}));
```